# How to punctuate a question

Tags: punctuation

So, I'm writing a dialogue and I'm not sure how to punctuate this question.

> "So where's the bag, you idiot?"

Would this be the correct way to do this even though the second part isn't a question and is instead referring to a person? Should the question mark go before 'you idiot'?

Comment: Answered at [How should a question ending in a statement be punctuated...?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269500/how-should-a-question-ending-in-a-statement-be-punctuated-as-ending-it-in-a-que/275583#275583).

Answer (score 1):

The way you've punctuated this sentence is correct. The question mark goes at the end.

Another example:

“I still got it, don’t I, baby?” she asked his reflection.

“More than ever, honey.”

Source: "Punctuation in Dialogue" by Beth Hill