# Can I use a question mark and the a comma or semicolon here? If not, how can I write this coherently?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, orthography, questions

What is the correct way to punctuate a sentence like the following?

> The problem of descrimpivity challenges us to answer the following questions: (1) which is more important, the bibble or the babble?; and (2) how do we explain why the potato trumps the tomato?

Spell check rejects both comma and semicolon after the question mark. But then how do I separate questions (1) and (2)?

Comment: Related: “[How should a question ending in a statement be punctuated, as ending it in a question mark seems a little off?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269500)”

Comment: Googling 'descrimpivity' gives me only two returns, both of which are the above question.

Comment: @Nigel J It's obviously a contrived example. // Using running text for such sequences of questions has long been seen to be less than ideal. If numbering is seen to be acceptable, why isn't bullet-pointing?

Comment: Break them up into an indented list for clarity. Alternately, use two sentences. // The first problem of ... is ... ? // The second problem of ... is ... ?